# Laravel Model Request unique two columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There is a model called `Fund` in my website. I created a `FundRequest` in `\Requests` directory and here is the rules

```
public function rules()
{
    $model = new Fund();
    $table = $model->getTable();
    return [
        'expenditure' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
        ],
        'date' => [
             'required',
             Rule::unique($table)->ignore($this->id)
        ],
    ];
}
```

The `date` must be unique and it works perfectly. But a column `user_id` is added to this model recently and the combination of `date`, `user_id` must be unique now. How can I add this constraint in the `FundRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $model = new Fund();
    $table = $model->getTable();
    return [
        'expenditure' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
        ],
        'date' => [
             'required',
             Rule::unique($table)->ignore($this->id)
        ],
        'user'=>'unique:user_id'
    ];
}
```

Comment: a user maybe repeated in the table for different dates. I'm not sure adding this rule allows such thing

Comment: if you add this rule available user_id is exactly one in that table

Comment: 'user' => [
             Rule::unique($table)->ignore($this->id)
        ],

Adding this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Add multiple columns in unique.

```
'date' => "unique:tableName,date,user_id"
```